# Anko DSL with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

today I have been working on translating one of my apps to a pure kotlin build as a test. I am struggling with array adapters currently, and getting this error.

```
File  from xml type layout resource ID #0x7f0c000a
```

This is my activity that has the error.

```
class KotlinTest : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val arr = Array(5, Int::toString)

        verticalLayout {


            id = R.id.test_text_layout

            textView {
                width = matchParent
                height = matchParent
                id = R.id.test_text_item
            }


            listView {
                id = R.id.test_text_view
            }
        }

        val cardAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = ArrayAdapter(ctx, R.id.test_text_layout, arr)

        val tempView: ListView = findViewById(R.id.test_text_view) as ListView

        tempView.adapter = cardAdapter

        cardAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }

}
```

And this is the ids.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <item name="test_text_item" type="id"/>
    <item name="test_text_view" type="id"/>
    <item name="test_text_layout" type="id"/>

</resources>
```

I have tried a few things but no luck, so any guidance would be appreciated. I assume I am just missing something dumb.

Comment: In which line does the error appear?

Comment: @voddan I don't get the error until `tempView.adapter = cardAdapter` which is when I assume it actually tries to build the arrayAdapter and inflate the layout, but I could be wrong. If I run it with that line and the one below it commented out I get just a blank activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this line `<item name="test_text_layout" type="id"/>`

Create file in `res/layout` dir, call it `test_text_layout.xml` and add following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In code of activity

```
val cardAdapter = ArrayAdapter(ctx, R.layout.test_text_layout, arr)
```

Cause of problem - you passed wrong parameter. From [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20T[]))

> resource  int: The resource ID for a **layout file** containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

If you want to get rid of xml completely, then you need to extend `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: And then there is no way to link that to the custom layout generated by Anko. That is what I was starting to assume the more I looked into it. It looks like for the application I am going for I will have to extend the ArrayAdapter. Thank you for confirming this.

Comment: @thechucklingatom you are welcome, ping me in chat if you will need help  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow